# String or binary data would be truncated issue

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Setting up a website for a game, however i ran into an issue on register page Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated., SQL state 22001 in SQLExecDirect in C:\root\htdocs\sites\regist.php on line 107
and trying to figure out how to fix it.

Tried changing [char] to [varchar] in database however it did not fix the issue.

```
EXEC [' . $_CONFIG['db_databases']['acc'] . '].[dbo].[usp_createAccount]
@account=\'' . $account . '\', @pw=\''.$md5pw.'\', @email=\''.$email.'\', 
@gefra=\''.$gefra.'\', 
@geant=\''.md5($_CONFIG['security_secretAnswerSalt'].$geant).'\', 
@birthday=\''.date($_CONFIG['web_date_format']['date'], strtotime($birthday)).'\', 
@ip = \'' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '\', 
@lang=\'' . $_CONFIG['web_default_lang'] . '\'
```

Comment: Post the query that is generated after variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Your table rows are smaller than values you are trying to insert, thus data is being truncated. Hard to tell which rows and which values without seeing the actual table DDL and SQL query, but it should be trivial with some debugging. 
It would make sense to dump the actual SQL query to a variable before executing - for debugging purposes and code readability.